# How to fetch 0mq socket structure from fd?

Tags: zeromq

We have an application in which we are listening on a socket. When clients connect, we need to know the per client “fd” and the peer address. This info can be fetched using the socket monitors. Subsequently, we need to send data separately for each client. (not send same data to all clients). Is there a standard API to get socket structure from “fd” which we can use in send API?

Comment: What exactly is `fd`?

Comment: fd => File descriptor

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `fd` is only used as a field of the `zmq_pollitem_t` struct used in `zmq_poll` or other pollers. There it is used for when you want to interface ZMQ sockets with other non-ZMQ pollers (so if you're using `zmq_poll` it shouldn't be set to anything other than `0`). So, in the case you are using a non-ZMQ poller, you're *setting* the `fd` value, not *getting* it.

Is this the use of `fd` you're referring to? If not, could you update your question to be more specific?

Comment: this isn't quite accurate - ZMQ_FD is only used for polling zmq sockets in *non-zmq* pollers, such as stdlib select, epoll, kqueue, libev, etc. Under normal zeromq usage with all zmq API calls, polling, etc. the zmq FD will never come up.

Comment: @minrk I know this, but I didn't make that clear enough, you're right. Updated.

Comment: @Timothy: In our case, we would like to start sending data only to a specific client after the client is connected. Server (listening) socket is not used for sending same data to all clients.   The socket monitors return the specific event per client with client _FD_ information. But the send APIs need **void pointers** to sockets rather than _FD_. Hence we want to know how to get per client **void pointer** to socket from per client _FD_?

Comment: @mmehra Pass the sending socket into zmq_send - not the receiving socket.  Where the message you send is routed is determined by what connections exist in your network and what identity message frames you send as part of your message.  Take a look at the parts dealing with ROUTER sockets and "identity" in the ZMQ guide.